# npm run build Reactjs errno1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

**Problem description**

I have a react project, the project runs well with the command 'npm start'. But in executing the command 'npm run build', I get this error:

```
 verbose node v12.16.3
 verbose npm  v6.14.4
 error code ELIFECYCLE
 error errno 1
 error demo1@6.1.5 build: `react-scripts build`
 error Exit status 1
 error Failed at the demo1@6.1.5 build script.
 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

This is my Package.json :

```
{
  "name": "demo1",
  "version": "6.1.5",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": ".",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "cp-cli build _site/metronic/preview/react && serve",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint src",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.{js,css,scss,html}\"",
    "rtl": "webpack"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  }

  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.11",
    "@formatjs/intl-pluralrules": "^1.3.5",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.9",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.33",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.6.0",
    "@tanem/svg-injector": "^8.0.35",
    "array-unique": "^0.3.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "cp-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "dentist": "^1.0.3",
    "fg-loadcss": "^2.1.0",
    "formik": "^2.0.6",
    "jss-rtl": "^0.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "object-path": "^0.11.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.16",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3"
     .
     .
  }
}
"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-proxy": "1.5.8",
    "copyfiles": "^2.1.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "serve": "^11.2.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-messages": "^2.0.4",
    "webpack-rtl-plugin": "^2.0.0"
  }
```

**Additional info**

I have tried solutions like: clean and delete node_modules and then install npm.But I'm still wrong.

**Full error description in log**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\..\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v12.16.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle demo1@6.1.5~prebuild: demo1@6.1.5
6 info lifecycle demo1@6.1.5~build: demo1@6.1.5
7 verbose lifecycle demo1@6.1.5~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle demo1@6.1.5~build: PATH: C:\..\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;G:\EAMS\EAMS _FINAL\EAMS.Web.Portal\ClientApp\node_modules\.bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\..\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\960145\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\..\.dotnet\tools;C:\..\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle demo1@6.1.5~build: CWD: G:\EAMS\EAMS _FINAL\EAMS.Web.Portal\ClientApp
10 silly lifecycle demo1@6.1.5~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts build' ]
11 silly lifecycle demo1@6.1.5~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle demo1@6.1.5~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: demo1@6.1.5 build: `react-scripts build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\960145\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:310:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\..\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid demo1@6.1.5
15 verbose cwd G:\..\ClientApp
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\..\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v12.16.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error demo1@6.1.5 build: `react-scripts build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the demo1@6.1.5 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: I hope you have just not shown the error part.. The npm log does not show anything other than what you have shown to us ??

Comment: No. The npm log shows exactly the same error.                                                                                      silly lifecycle demo1@6.1.5~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts build' ]                                  silly lifecycle demo1@6.1.5~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null                                                     info lifecycle demo1@6.1.5~build: Failed to exec build script                                                   verbose stack Error: demo1@6.1.5 build: `react-scripts build`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
npm cache clean --force
delete node_modules (manually)
npm install
npm run rtl
npm start
```

Comment: In the description section above, I did these steps, but there is still an error